# .NET 7 -> .NET 8 MauiUIApplicationDelegate could not be found

Tags: maui, .net-8.0

of course I decided to update from .net7 to .net 8 on this, the first day of the release. I am getting the errors below.  My google-foo has not been very good.  any ideas are appreciated?  TIA

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MauiUIApplicationDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) BWD (net8.0-ios13.6)    C:\SoftwareSource\BWD\BWD\Platforms\iOS\AppDelegate.cs

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MauiUIApplicationDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) BWD (net7.0-maccatalyst)    C:\SoftwareSource\BWD\BWD\Platforms\iOS\AppDelegate.cs  6   Active

Comment: I found this issue on github, however, this did not seem to solve the problem. github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36667 - ** Correction, it kinda solves the problem, but kinda not.  The error seems to be intermittent now.  If I delete the bin & obj directories, the error seems to go away, but it does return.

Answer (score 1):

For me what fixed it was to target ios 17.0 instead of 16.1

17.0

Comment: <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">17.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

Comment: I bet that is what fixed things.  We futzed around with various versions defined in the csproj file.

Comment: Upgraded again 2 days ago to the latest Visual Studio and Nuget packages, .NET SDK, etc. was back at this problem again, and (again) updated the supported platform to 17.2.... fixed it.   I wish the error message would point to that instead of this stupid/cryptic error message.

Answer (score 0):

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MauiUIApplicationDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

About this error, you can check this issue in MAUI: [Upgrading to 8.0.0-rc.2.9511 breaks the app. Loses references to MauiUIApplicationDelegate #18739](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18739).

According to [Redth's reply](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18739#issuecomment-1811502387), you can install .NET 8 GA to fix it:

> There was a change between previews to the iOS workload which required
> an update to that workload in order to use the newer MAUI package.
> This should be resolved with the GA release.
>
> Typically we will avoid such changes between service releases without
> coordinating the updated workload set for MAUI as well, but
> unfortunately for preview releases this isn't always possible.
>
> Solution: Please install .NET 8 GA, and the workloads as well.

**Update:**

Creating a new .NET 8 project and then migrating the code into it can make a difference.

Comment: I have tried just about every thing listed in that thread.  I have installed the .net 8 GA.  I have updated the VS 2022 to the release for .net 8.  I have updated my workloads.  I have deleted the obj and bin directories.  I have closed and reopened VS.  I still get the error.  Other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: This is very embarrassing, and I have also seen other users feedback in the issue that it doesn't work. Currently, there are still major and minor issues with .NET 8. You can continue to follow up on it to see if there are any new solutions. Also, if it is not particularly necessary, please keep it at .NET 7.

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding how to go back to .net 7 in maui?

Comment: I decided to create a new .NET 8 project, copied all of my code in, and it seems to be working.  I hate that upgrades are so hard now, but it isn't a real killer and I'm back off and running.

Comment: I also worked with redth on the maui team and we figured out what was going on, so it's all good now.  Upgrades are always hard.

Comment: Congratulations for letting it work normally! I edited the answer according to your solution. : )  *"Upgrades are always hard."*  Yes, I am in full agreement.